# A bug with the reputation voting system?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, voting, user-interface

I have encountered a bug in your software.

Whenever I click on +1 or -1 ratings and I'm not allowed to, the reputation is shown to go up and then immediately it goes down.This looks like a bug to me.

Comment: I think it's more a delay in it realizing you can't do that. I've seen it before, too, and just took it to be that.

Comment: There are delays updating stats all over the place in the SE software, and they seem to have gotten worse of late.  It is what it is.  So long as the counts work out after 24 hours it's no big deal.

Comment: If it is a bug, What do you think should be the expected behavior?

Answer (score 11):

As the Germans say: Jein...

It's probably just the most practical implementation. The front end is optimistic and immediately updates, but the backend actually checks and refuses the request, which causes the front end to revert its optimistic display update. The alternative would be to wait until the backend returns with its sanity check, which would make the interface more sluggish. The other alternative would be to replicate all necessary permission state on the client so the front end can make a decision itself whether it should work or not, but this makes things much, much more complicated.

In the end, there's no real bug in terms of something going wrong, it's just a minor interface glitch under rare circumstances, for which the cost-benefit ratio of fixing it very much are against the fix.